# Merge a grouped dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Given data in the following format:

```
    Time                        Id          Status  In      SId   Value
0   2018-02-10 23:09:06.843000  1.139982    OPEN    False   17144126    8.80
1   2018-02-10 23:11:09.954000  1.139982    OPEN    False   17144126    8.80
2   2018-02-10 23:11:09.954000  1.139982    OPEN    False   16848301    2.88
3   2018-02-10 23:13:09.943000  1.139982    OPEN    False   16848301    2.90
```

I want to transform the data to following format:

```
    Time                        SId_17144126 SId_16848301
0   2018-02-10 23:09:06.843000  8.80         Na
1   2018-02-10 23:11:09.954000  8.80         2.88
2   2018-02-10 23:13:09.943000  Na           2.90
```

Im trying with the following code but it wont work since merge is not available for a grouped object:

```
groups = df.groupby(['Id','SId'])
groups.merge(how='outer', left_on='Time', right_on='Time')
```